# Improve plot quality with Plotly and panel.interact

Tags: python, plotly, holoviz-panel

I am trying to improve the quality (resolution) of a plotly plot when using panel.interactive (both in Jupyter and when saved as a file). I am able to improve the quality when using plotly directly with a ‘config’ given to the “show” function as below only for saved file:

```
config = {
  'toImageButtonOptions': {
    'format': 'svg', # one of png, svg, jpeg, webp
    'scale': 1.0 # Multiply title/legend/axis/canvas sizes by this factor
  }
}
fig.show(config=config)
```

However, I am unable to reproduce this solution when using panel.interactive in the example below:

```
pn.extension('plotly')

def get_plot_pillars(x_last_data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1)), columns=list('A'))
    df = df.iloc[-x_last_data:]
    df = df.reset_index()
    df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['index'], value_vars=['A'])
    fig = px.line(df, x = 'index', y =  'value', template = "plotly_white")
    fig.update_layout(legend_title="")
    fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)')
    return fig
    
interact_compo_pnl = pn.interact(get_plot_pillars,
                                 x_last_data = pn.widgets.IntSlider(name='x last data', start=1, end=50, step=1, value=1))

pn.Row(
    pn.Column(interact_compo_pnl[0][0]),
    interact_compo_pnl[1]    
)
```